# Use ActiveMQ as Event Broker in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

In my wso2 esb 4.5.0-environment I want to send messages to ActiveMQ via the event mediator.

By default, the event mediator is connected to an internal, memorybased eventbroker in wso2 esb.

There is a possibility to change the event broker to WSO2 Message broker. This change is achieved by editing the file `$wso2esb_home/repository/conf/event-broker.xml`.

In the file there is an example config for WSO2 MB, but not for ActiveMQ.

What are the configuration settings for ActiveMQ as eventbroker?

Comment: i have exactly the same problem. were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up solving this issue by developing a custom mediatior that communicates with ActiveMQ using JMS.